# Why GROUP_CONCAT add coma separated when used in 1 column but not if use multiple columns?

Tags: php, mysql

I have 1 table with 6 columns (id, username, start, end, flag, timestamp) and I am trying to use GROUP_CONCAT to concatenate the columns. 
Everything works fine except that I have no separator for the columns.

`SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(start, end, flag SEPARATOR ';') FROM time;`

The result is the following:

`15531696461553177094End Time;15531779481553177962End Time;15531779561553177960End Lunch`

What we see here is the columns from 2 tables that have the same structure and are concatenated using the separator `;`

Before in a different server, the columns were divided by `,` so the result was:

`1553169646,1553177094,End Time;1553177948,1553177962,End Time;1553177956,1553177960,End Lunch`

I don't know what is different in this new server as I have no access in the old one.

Did anyone face something like this before? I am stuck in this as the following code of my script is based on the previews output. I would like to have the same output:

`1553169646,1553177094,End Time;1553177948,1553177962,End Time;1553177956,1553177960,End Lunch`

Answer (score 1):

You can write as to concat per record column values and switching record add `;` at the switching of every record,

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS(',',start, end, flag) SEPARATOR ';') FROM time;
```

[CONCAT_WS()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws) stands for Concatenate With Separator and is a special form of CONCAT().

Comment: Great thank you. I was wondering if is possible to use `UNION ALL` as well with  `CONCAT_WS` for example: 

`SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(ab.start, ab.end, ab.flag SEPARATOR ';') AS ids FROM ((SELECT start, end, flag FROM time WHERE username = ? AND end<= ?) UNION ALL (SELECT start, end, flag FROM lunch WHERE username = ? AND end<= ?)) ab;`  

This works for me but without a comma separator.

Comment: But you didn't use `CONCAT_WS` in your query, it will work, give it a try.

Comment: I tried but seems I have something wrong in the query:
`SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(ab.start, ab.end, ab.flag SEPARATOR ';') AS ids 
FROM ((SELECT CONCAT_WS(',', start, end, flag)  
      FROM time)  UNION ALL (SELECT CONCAT_WS (',', start, end, flag) 
      FROM lunch)) ab; ` the error given is `#1054 - Unknown column 'ab.start' in 'field list' ` I am not sure where is the mistake in the query. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, [`Concat()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) the columns using comma. Then, you can do `Group_Concat()`:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(start, ',', end, ',', flag) SEPARATOR ';') FROM time;
```